# PHP/SQL get all lat/lng locations from multiple other lat/lng locations using one SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables: a Map table that has about 3,000 lat/lng pairs representing real-world "marker" locations; and a Buildings table that has a few hundred lat/lng pairs also representing real-world building locations. What I am trying to do is to get all of the markers that are visible from all of the buildings, assuming the buildings have a "vision range" defined separately. I have a fully working PHP script that runs successfully:

```
<?php

// query the Buildings table to get the building data we need
$sql = "SELECT type, lat, lng FROM Buildings;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $allBuildings[] = $row;
}

$result -> close();

// count how many buildings there are to save time in the loop
$buildingsNumber = count($allBuildings);

// this is the key query, which runs a SELECT query for every building so that only the markers visible by the buildings are shown
for ($i = 0; $i < $buildingsNumber; $i++) {
    // get the building's lat/lng
    $lat = $allBuildings[$i]["lat"];
    $lng = $allBuildings[$i]["lng"];

    // get the building's vision range in metres
    $distance = $buildings[$allBuildings[$i]["type"]]["vision_range"];

    // this is the core query. it is a radius search using lat/lngs with the centre being the building's location and the radius being its vision_range
    $sql = "SELECT Map.lat, Map.lng,
    (6378137 * acos(cos(radians($lat)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians($lng)) + sin(radians($lat)) * sin(radians(lat))))
    AS distance FROM Map
    HAVING distance < $distance;";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $markersArray[] = $row;
    }
}

?>
```

The problem is, for that many individual queries the result is returned in about 20-30 seconds. This makes sense, since it seems that a round-trip from my PHP server to my MySQL server takes about 30ms. I need a query that returns results near-instantly, so ideally I want to avoid these multiple round trips and send one query that returns one set of results.

I have previously tried using mysqli_multi_query in different queries, but I've never gotten it to work successfully. I was also thinking of concatenating the queries but I'm not sure this would work either. Has anyone successfully been able to do something similar? Or can anyone suggest a way to re-write my script that would only require one SELECT query to be run?

Many thanks,
George

Comment: Hey @Arj, i think that one of the things that you can do to considerably reduce your execution time by building the query once inside that for loop and then executing it only once immediately after `for` - and also have you thought about using PDO? :D You can eliminate that while loop aswell :D

Comment: Hi emma, and thanks for taking the time to respond. When you say "build the query", do you mean concatenating and executing a multi query? Or something else? Also, yes I've thought about PDO but I am building this functionality in an existing application using existing architecture, which doesn't currently use PDO. it's probably too late to switch now :)

Comment: I think you can do the math in for loop and seve it inside an array and then use that array to build the query: `SELECT lat, long FROM Map WHERE vision_range < $distance AND vision_range < $distance AND...ORDER BY vision_range ASC` - i've never answered on stackoverflow so i'm sorry if i say something wrong or not conclusive :D - i mean just build that query once... and execute it once(of course again `$distance` in this case will be built outside your query inside the for loop and then you execute it once the loop is done)

Comment: P.S:`$distance` in my comment is not the distance variable that you have inside the for loop, it is the result of that trigonometric calculation

Comment: Remove all the php from the question, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks emma. Just re-wrote the script to use mysqli_multi_query. Execution time is now 0.25551795959473 seconds :) Note that this query requires the MYSQLI_USE_RESULT flag like so: $result = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);, otherwise it returns an empty result (tore my hair out for the last few hours over this one). I'm happy for you to write an answer - I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to emma for the suggestion. Here is the above script, re-written to move the SELECT queries outside the for loop and use a multi query for the result:

```
<?php

// query the Buildings table to get the building data we need
$sql = "SELECT type, lat, lng FROM Buildings;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $allBuildings[] = $row;
}

$result -> close();

// count how many buildings there are to save time in the loop
$buildingsNumber = count($allBuildings);

// this is the key query, which runs a SELECT query for every building so that only the markers visible by the buildings are shown
for ($i = 0; $i < $buildingsNumber; $i++) {
    // get the building's lat/lng
    $lat = $allBuildings[$i]["lat"];
    $lng = $allBuildings[$i]["lng"];

    // get the building's vision range in metres
    $distance = $buildings[$allBuildings[$i]["type"]]["vision_range"];

    // this is the core query. it is a radius search using lat/lngs with the centre being the building's location and the radius being its vision_range
    $sql .= "SELECT Map.lat, Map.lng,
    (6378137 * acos(cos(radians($lat)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians($lng)) + sin(radians($lat)) * sin(radians(lat))))
    AS distance FROM Map
    HAVING distance < $distance;";
}

// note two important things: multi query doesn't work without the MYSQLI_USE_RESULT flag, and we don't close a multi query result otherwise we get server errors
$result = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $markersArray[] = $row;
}

?>
```

Note the importance of my last comment regarding multi query, as it caused me a lot of grief.